# Webdav server on opensolaris

Tags: apache-http-server, opensolaris, webdav

i need to install a webdav server on Opensolaris, it seems that the mod_dav module is not in the distro and hard to find on the web.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: My problem was wich apache to use, bith were install i have set up my apache 2, every modules was there but i didn't the right modules configurtion file which is in /etc/apache2/2.2/conf.d.

To finish the configuration i used :
http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-webdav-with-apache2-on-debian-etch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was wich apache to use, bith were install i have set up my apache 2, every modules was there but i didn't the right modules configurtion file which is in /etc/apache2/2.2/conf.d.

To finish the configuration i used :
http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-webdav-with-apache2-on-debian-etch